# No such file or directory: Running Ruby as an interpreter script for execv()

Tags: c, execve

I'm writing a C program that passes data to a Ruby script. The snippet of code in main.c is below. Whenever I run, I receive an error from execv() that there is no such file or directory. I guessed that I didn't add my file to the PATH but I did and I still ended up with the same outcome.

```
int temp =  execv("#!/usr/bin/ruby xmlReader.rb", list);
if (spec == -1)
      printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does; `execv()` requires individual arguments, and it overlays the calling program anyway. Consider `system()`, though the shebang line won't work this way.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec*()` family of system calls are very low level, they *replace* the executing program with the program mentioned as the first argument, so there's no return value unless there's an error. Upon success, your program is entirely gone, overlaid with the new program. It's a one-way program-execution chain.

It doesn't know how to run command lines, and `exec()` is usually usually is done after a `fork()` operation. You almost certainly don't want to do this.

What you probably want is `int temp = system("ruby xmlreader.rb");` which will run the command line given in a subprocess (ultimately using `fork` and `exec`, though this aspect is invisible to you), wait for it to complete, then return the exit value to you.